# Windows CE 6 Wordpad replacement

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder, wordpad

I'm developing a Win CE 6 OS image and want to make it fit in the "Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Core Run-Time License".

This means, among other things, that I have to remove the Wordpad application.
From a product service and development perspective I'd like to replace it with something similar but free.

One thought was to do a simple editor in C#/CF.Net but I'd rather like to find something which can be plugged in and works, preferable free or at least cheaper than the 15$ per unit a bumped up license would cost.

Is there any suitably licensed text editors out there which are available for Win CE 6?

I don't need a rich text editor just a simple text editor to edit xml and text configuration files. The editor must be able to handle utf-8/unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own simple file editor in C#/WinForms. Not great, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

[cke](http://www.animaniak.com/cke/cke_main.asp) is quite good and I'm sure you can make some kind of a deal with it's author. [CEdit](http://www.logicalsky.com/CEdit_Download.php) is another good one.

Comment: Isn't it the same thing? Well, apart from phone module which is not always active but I don't think editor would ever want to use that :)

Comment: Not really. Windows Mobile (here after WM) includes certain requirements not necessary met on a WinCE image. These includes e.g. screen resolution, hardware buttons.
See http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehall/archive/2007/01/17/windows-mobile-and-windows-embedded-ce-what-s-the-difference.aspx
 for more differences. I'm looking for something simple, preferrably in C, to put in an OS-image

Comment: cke also seems to be for PocketPC only (i.e. Windows Mobile).